# Set-ADAccountExpiration Isn't Set on the Local Time Format

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I created a PowerShell script that disables AD Users in Bulk, however, when the script runs the cmdlet `Set-ADAccountExpiration -Identity $User -DateTime "$EndDate"` where the $EndDate comes from Windows Form code below, he sets the expiration date for the AD User account as US Format (08/03/2021 - MM/DD/YYYY) instead of 'Global' Format (03/09/2021 - DD/MM/YYYY) even when I print the $EndDate I get 'Global' Format: `01/09/2021 00:00:00`

```
$Form = New-Object Windows.Forms.Form -Property @{
    StartPosition   = [Windows.Forms.FormStartPosition]::CenterScreen
    Size            = New-Object Drawing.Size 300, 230
    Text            = 'Select User Contract Date'
    Topmost         = $true
    FormBorderStyle = 'FixedDialog'
    MaximizeBox     = $false
}

$Calendar = New-Object Windows.Forms.MonthCalendar -Property @{
    ShowTodayCircle   = $false
    MaxSelectionCount = 1
}

$Form.Controls.Add($Calendar)

$OKButton = New-Object Windows.Forms.Button -Property @{
    Location     = New-Object Drawing.Point 95, 165
    Size         = New-Object Drawing.Size 75, 23
    Text         = 'OK'
    DialogResult = [Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK
}

$Form.AcceptButton = $OKButton
$Form.Controls.Add($OKButton)

$Result = $Form.ShowDialog()

if ($Result -eq [Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK) {
    $EndDate = $Calendar.SelectionStart
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be easier for you to use a [DateTimePicker object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker) instead of the `MonthCalendar`.

On a DateTimePicker, you can set the date format quite easily:

```
$Calendar = [System.Windows.Forms.DateTimePicker]::new()
$Calendar.Format = [System.Windows.Forms.DateTimePickerFormat]::Custom
$Calendar.CustomFormat = 'dd/MM/yyyy'
```